# Application of the Multivariate Chain Rule

Tags: calculus

I'm working on a problem about the application of the multivariate chain rule, and I think I've got the right answer, but I would appreciate if someone could verify what I've done.

*Problem: $F(x,y) = f(g(x,y),h(x),k(y))$ where $f, g, h, k$ are differentiable in their own domains. Find the partial derivatives of $F$ with respect to $x$ and $y$.*

I have:

$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial h}\frac{\partial h}{\partial x} + 0$

and

$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} + 0 + \frac{\partial f}{\partial k}\frac{\partial k}{\partial y}$

Is this right and can I be more explicit than this?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks Great. Is $f$ vector valued function or is it scalar valued function? i.e. what is range or $f$?

Comment: The problem doesn't explicitly state whether $f$ is vector or scalar valued, but I'm assuming it's vector valued. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer to write $f(u,v,w)$ and then have
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} +\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}h'(x)\,.$$
For completeness, you might want to indicate where you evaluate the partials of $f$.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Ted. What exactly do you mean when you say, "where you evaluate the partials of $f$." Is this a reference to the dimensionality of $f$'s partials?

Comment: No, I mean that you evaluate $f$ and its partial derivatives at the point $(g(x,y),h(x),k(y))$.

Comment: Alright, thank you, Ted.